# More ergonomic / convenient STL algorithm calls -- sort order & member field extraction using std::invoke

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

While we patiently wait for `ranges` in C++20, it can still get somewhat frustrating to write `begin()`, `end()` and `micro-lambda`s to specify "sort order" and "field extraction".

It is the latter, "field extraction" which I find is very commonly needed, but rarely discussed. The `C++11 lambda` has made it easier but the syntax is still very verbose for a very common task. There was even a recent slack/cpplang question about it. Inspired by [a comment](https://youtu.be/W2tWOdzgXHA?t=1608) in Sean Parent's famous Seasoning talk, where he suggested using `std::bind` to abstract this syntax, I looked into modern alternatives. `std::bind` has a bad name for being large and slow. More modern is `std::invoke` from C++17.

So my proof of concept below tries to get to some terser syntax for these common operations using `std::invoke`.

I am looking for feedback on:

- Coding style
- Constraining that template - with / without c++20 concepts (it's wide open right now)
- The new, terser calling syntax for STL algos which operate on some user defined class and require field/member extraction and potentially sorting on those.
- `std::sort` is just one example. This could work for std::accumulate or anything really. Would I need up to 115 such wrapper templates? is there a better way.

Code size *may* still be a concern (even with `std::invoke` rather than `std::bind`) as shown by the the generated [ASM here](https://godbolt.org/z/byOAk6). The base case of the traditional lambda generates ~2000 lines of assembly code (LOA). Then **each** of the "new syntax" lines generates a further 2000 LOA -bringin it to ~8000 LOA in total for `clang-9 -O3`. Because the `sortby` template is stamped out for each type of lambda.

I haven't measured performance. Will all this code slow it down significantly with a lot of boilerplate and indirection, or is it just code size that suffers?

**EDIT**: Benchmark data has [now been added below](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235215/212940).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Employee {
  int         id;
  std::string firstname;
  std::string lastname;
  int         yob;

  [[nodiscard]] int getAge() const noexcept { return 2020 - yob; }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Employee& e) {
    return stream << e.id << ", " << e.firstname << ", " << e.lastname << ", " << e.yob << ", "
                  << e.getAge();
  }
};

namespace os::algo {

// the following 6 lines make it possible
template <typename Container, typename Member, typename Comparison = std::less<>>
void sortby(Container& c, Member&& m, Comparison comp = Comparison()) {
  std::sort(c.begin(), c.end(), [&m, &comp](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    return comp(std::invoke(m, a), std::invoke(m, b));
  });
}

} // namespace os::algo

int main() {

  using os::algo::sortby;

  auto employees = std::vector<Employee>{
      {1, "James", "Smith", 2008},
      {2, "John", "Jones", 1998},
      {3, "Sarah", "Evans", 1968},
      {4, "Michelle", "Harris", 1978},
  };

  // BEFORE: This is what's required with normal STL calls
  std::sort(employees.begin(), employees.end(),
            [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.firstname < b.firstname; });

  // AFTER: and now we can do this...

  // the easy part -- no begin(), end()

  // trivial, terse sorting by any member field
  sortby(employees, &Employee::firstname);

  // trivially specify sort direction
  sortby(employees, &Employee::yob, std::greater<>());

  // can use getters too
  sortby(employees, &Employee::getAge, std::greater<>());

  for (const auto& e: employees) std::cout << e << "\n";

  // std::sort is but one example. The same technique applies to any STL algorithm

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer `std::begin(c)` over `c.begin()`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thanks! I find that interesting. I have always wondered which is preferred and for what reason, but not found any content. Is your advice just for this case where we don't know what kind of container we have, or in general?

Comment: Really what I want to say in the template signature is: 

a) `Container` is really a `Container<T>` b) you can call `begin/end` on `Container` and c) `std::invoke(Member, T)`  gives me some type `F` (the field type), which when you call `Comparison(F,F)` you get a `bool`. And throw readable compile errors (or ignore the template) if any of the above are not true.

Comment: The main reason for using `std::begin()` and `std::end()` is that they allow iteration over containers that don't implement the class member functions `begin()` and `end()`, such as regular C-style arrays. You can overload `std::begin()` and `std::end()` to provide iteration over classes that don't provide that functionality natively.

Comment: OK, yes, so in generic code, where we don't know what the container is (such as here) we should use `std::begin`. Makes. sense. But I shouldn't change the code above right ;-) ? Or because there are no answers yet, I should? Wouldn't want to upset any community police.

Comment: Don't change the code. It's also instructive for others to see the original code and the discussion around it.

Comment: OK. No one will ever see that in the comments without an answer, I thought. but if you will write one, then that can be included there.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I just tried this: Didn't work for me. Can you really use `std::begin()` on a C-style array? It only works when the array was declared in the same scope as you call `std::begin()` (or a ranged for loop in my case, which is juts syntactic sugar for that). As soon as you pass the C-style array to a function, it decays to a pointer, and you can't call `std::begin()` anymore. This is the state of the union since Kernigan and Ritchie. Don't think modern C++ has managed to change that? I don't want to pass sizes and use for(int i=0...) style loops. So `std::array<>` does add value here?

Comment: It indeed only works if it's declared in the same scope, as soon as you pass it to a function it decays to a pointer, even in modern C++. I mentioned it to illustrate that `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are compatible with a lot more than just the STL containers.

Comment: The type of an array is preserved when it's passed by reference and the size is in the signature, e.g. `template<std::size_t N> void f(const int (&array)[N])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, your `sortby` *when used in the style shown, with data members,* will not be quite as fast as if you used the STL with a lambda. Look at the difference in assembly between

```
struct Date {
    int year, month, day;
};

void test1(std::array<Date, 100>& a) {
    sortby(a, &Date::month);
    sortby(a, &Date::year);
}

void test2(std::array<Date, 100>& a) {
    sortby(a, [](const auto& x){ return x.month; });
    sortby(a, [](const auto& x){ return x.year; });
}
```

In `test1`, the difference between `&Date::month` and `&Date::year` is encoded in the runtime *value* of the member pointer. In `test2`, the difference is encoded in the compile-time *type* of the lambda. So `test2` instantiates two different template instantiations, whereas `test1` calls the same instantiation twice with different inputs. (But if both calls are inlined, the optimizer *might* be able to hide the difference.)

However, this is not the fault of your `sortby` helper; it's the fault of using member pointers instead of custom lambdas. You can observe the same differences happening if you call `std::sort` with a function pointer, versus calling `std::sort` with an instance of some bespoke type such as `std::less<>` or `std::greater<>`.

---

You pass `Member&& m` by forwarding reference, but then you use it as an lvalue (without forwarding it again). I think I've mentioned before: if you don't intend to forward an argument, then you shouldn't be using a forwarding reference with it. In this case, you just need to look at the value of the member-pointer `m` without modifying it, so `const Member& m` would be appropriate. Or, since member data pointers and custom lambdas are both going to be small trivial types, and member function pointers are also trivial types (if slightly larger), we should seriously think about taking `Member m` directly by value.

Notice that you already take `Comparison comp` by value.

The comment about using `std::begin(c)` over `c.begin()` is accurate. If you want your `sortby` template to work for C-style arrays, then you should use `std::begin(c)`. Remember, you can't pass arrays *by value* (they decay to pointers) — but you can certainly pass arrays *by reference*, and that's what you're doing here when you `sortby` an array "in place."

The vast majority of lambdas you write should just take `[&]`. I don't see any benefit to writing `[&m, &comp]` when it ends up meaning the same thing as `[&]`.

So I'd write your helper like this:

```
template<class Container, class Member, class Comparison = std::less<>>
void sortby(Container& c, Member m, Comparison comp = Comparison()) {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    std::sort(begin(c), end(c), [&](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        return comp(std::invoke(m, a), std::invoke(m, b));
    });
}
```

`using std::begin;` is the "`std::swap` two-step," familiar to anyone who's used `std::swap` before. It means "consider using `std::begin` for unqualified calls, but if someone has provided a better-matching ADL version of `begin`, then we'll happily use that version instead." This is certainly overkill — I mean we could just write `std::begin(c), std::end(c),` — but the two-step is how all the [standard customization points](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.range#1.sentence-2) are meant to be used as far as I know, so we might as well stick to it.

Vice versa, I would personally shy away from using the two-step in `main` —

```
using os::algo::sortby;
```

This seems more confusing than helpful. Are you expecting that someone else *might* provide a better-matching ADL `sortby`? If not, then `sortby(x,y,z)` will always mean `os::algo::sortby(x,y,z)`... and if it *is* `os::algo::sortby`, [why not say so?](https://www.gsarchive.net/mikado/webopera/mk212d.html)

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful again. Re forward ref: Yes this was written before the other question (or at least before your answer), so yes I have learned that lesson. The points about ADL and begin/end are useful too. I just tend to assume that c-style arrays will decay, if not now, then later when the code gets refactored in some way. But the general point is obviously still true.

Comment: re [&] vs [&m,&comp] I understand it is not different, but I guess I felt that in a "library style helper" it is worth "documenting" and constraining what we are using. [&] always feels like a bit like a "broad sweep" to me. In "application code" I tend to write [&] because it is terser, unless the scope is more than say 10-15 lines.

Comment: The comments about ADL for os::algo::sortby are interesting. I didn't write `using os::algo::sortby` for any ADL reason (probably because I am not yet fully aware of all ADL implications yet). I wrote it quite simply for DRY terseness. My idea was, if I am going to call `sortby`  more than say 2-3 times in a single scope and it has a somewhat verbose fully qualified name -> write one `using` statement and then don't repeat the namespace part. Is that flawed? I understand why statements like `using namespace std` are very bad. Is this too far in that direction? Should I stick to writing FQNs?

Comment: Finally in the discussion about code size / speed ( I will do some more benchmarking and report back) it occurred to me that if code size were a concern then one could consider using type erasure https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/03/18/what-is-type-erasure/ for the callback inside `sortby`. This will probably be  slower (?) due to virtual dispatch inside the type erased type, but might be a reasonable tradeoff in some situations. Although the virtual call would end up being once/twice per comparison right?

Comment: benchmark data has been added below: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235215/212940

Comment: Why not `using std::begin, std::end;`?

Answer (score 1):

Some benchmarking data as promised:

Cut to the chase, results:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark              Time             CPU   Iterations
--------------------------------------------------------
stl/100             3940 ns         3940 ns       173735
member/100          4756 ns         4756 ns       147187
lambda/100          3979 ns         3979 ns       177405
getter/100          8768 ns         8768 ns        79665
stlgetter/100       3993 ns         3993 ns       179926
```

Summary:

- Passing a member variable to the helper does incur a cost (~15-20%, and ~ 10% for bigger containers) as predicted by @Quuxplusone and using a lambda (ie fixing the offset in a distinct compile time type) does get rid of that extra cost (back to normal STL levels).
- Slight shock (for me at least) was that passing the address of a getter into our helper slows things down by ~2x. Put in an extra benchmark with the STL using the getters, and as expected that is ~nil cost compared to base case.

Attempt at a conclusion:

- This is not a zero cost abstraction.
- However, for the most commonly requested use-case (eg slack/cpplang query), which is "sort by this public member", there is "only" a 15-20% (and ~10% for bigger containers) penalty relative to a custom lambda, but this has a code size benefit and is not actually caused by the abstraction as such (but to do with static/runtime resolution of the "address").
- passing "getters" seems to have a weirdly large costs, needs further investigation.

Here is the benchmark code (using Google Benchmark):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

struct Date {
  int year, month, day;
  [[nodiscard]] int get_year() const noexcept { return year; }
  [[nodiscard]] int get_month() const noexcept { return month; }
  [[nodiscard]] int get_day() const noexcept { return day; }
};

namespace os::algo {

// the following 6 lines make it possible
template <typename Container, typename Member, typename Comparison = std::less<>>
void sortby(Container& c, const Member& m, const Comparison& comp = Comparison()) {
  std::sort(std::begin(c), std::end(c), [&](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    return comp(std::invoke(m, a), std::invoke(m, b));
  });
}

} // namespace os::algo

std::vector<Date> get_random_dates(std::size_t size) {
  std::random_device                 rnd_device;
  std::mt19937                       engine{1}; // rnd_device()};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> year_dist{1940, 2025};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> month_dist{1, 12};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> day_dist{1, 28}; // ignore complexities

  auto dates = std::vector<Date>{};
  dates.reserve(size);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    dates.push_back({year_dist(engine), month_dist(engine), day_dist(engine)});
  }
  return dates;
}

void stl(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto ds = get_random_dates(state.range(0));
  for (auto _: state) {
    std::sort(ds.begin(), ds.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.month < b.month; });
    std::sort(ds.begin(), ds.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.year < b.year; });
  }
}
BENCHMARK(stl)->Arg(100);

void member(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto ds = get_random_dates(state.range(0));
  for (auto _: state) {
    os::algo::sortby(ds, &Date::month);
    os::algo::sortby(ds, &Date::year);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(member)->Arg(100);

void lambda(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto ds = get_random_dates(state.range(0));
  for (auto _: state) {
    os::algo::sortby(ds, [](const auto& x) { return x.month; });
    os::algo::sortby(ds, [](const auto& x) { return x.year; });
  }
}
BENCHMARK(lambda)->Arg(100);

void getter(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto ds = get_random_dates(state.range(0));
  for (auto _: state) {
    os::algo::sortby(ds, &Date::get_month);
    os::algo::sortby(ds, &Date::get_year);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(getter)->Arg(100);

void stlgetter(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto ds = get_random_dates(state.range(0));
  for (auto _: state) {
    std::sort(ds.begin(), ds.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.get_month() < b.get_month(); });
    std::sort(ds.begin(), ds.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.get_year() < b.get_year(); });
  }
}
BENCHMARK(stlgetter)->Arg(100);
```

I also did a quick study on code size. I compiled a stripped down version of above code (no random gen, and no google benchmark lib) using `clang-9` with `-O3` and checked the binary executable size. I commented out all sorting for the base case and then uncommented each one of the methods in turn. As well as binary size I recorded "lines of assembly" (LOA) [shown in godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6goZwo).

Results:

```
// base size without any sort function: 17248 bytes / 219 LOA

// size with stl: 21864 bytes / 1913 LOA

// size with member: 17984 bytes / 970 LOA

// size with lambda: 22072 bytes / 1941 LOA

// size with getter: 22656 bytes / 1128 LOA
```

The only anomaly is the highest binary size and very low LOA for "getter". But otherwise this makes sense. Generally:

```
"Info encoded in Fixed types" (ie lambdas) => 
bigger binary => 
higher LOA => 
and (from above) faster performance
```

This "code size conclusion" is quite different from my initial impression in the original post. There I thought that the `sortby` helper was increasing code size. It is not. If that was really happening it was a compiler optimisation artefact. This more proper test shows the logical conclusion just above.

Comment: Getters having a bigger cost is not surprising: Lack of inlining means the function-call-protocol with registers preserved, reserved, potentially used and the like, as well as stack-interactions has to be adhered to. Also, there is the call and return itself. A different approach you might want to compare is building a comparator from a projection and a matching comparator, the latter potentially defaulted to `std::less<>`.